# Multiple atomic updates using MongoDB?

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am using Codeigniter and Alex Bilbie's MongoDB library. 
In my API that I am developing users can upload images and other users can comment on them.
I have chosen to include the comments as sub documents to the images.

Each comment contains:

- Fullname (of author)
- Comment
- Created_at

So in other words. The users full name is "hard coded" into each comment so if they
later decides to change their names I have a problem.

I read that I can use atomic updates to update all occurrences of the name (like in comments) but how can I do this using Alex´s library? Can I update all places where the name is wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is how the image document looks like with the comments.
I think that it is pretty strange that MongoDB encourage the use of subdocuments but then does not include a way to update multiple items in an array.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4e9ead773dc793dc01020000"),
    "description": "An image",
    "category": "accident",
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": ObjectId("4e96bd063dc7937202000000"),
            "fullname": "James Bond",
            "comment": "This is a comment.",
            "created_at": "2011-10-19 13:02:40"
        }
    ],
    "created_at": "2011-10-19 12:59:03"
}
```

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with codeignitor, but mb mongodb shell syntax will help you:

```
db.comments.update( {"Fullname":"Andrew Orsich"}, 
                    { $set : { Fullname: "New name"} }, false, true )
```

Last true flag indicate that you want update multiple documents. So it is possible to update all comments in one update operation.

BTW: denormalazing (not 'hard coding') data in mongodb and nosql in general is usual operation. Also operation that require update a lot of documents usually work async. But it is up to you.

**Update:**

```
db.comments.update( {"comments.Fullname":"Andrew Orsich"}, 
                    { $set : { comments.$.Fullname: "New name"} }, false, true )
```

But, above query will update full name in first comment on nested array. If you need to affect changes to more than one array element you will need to use multiple update statements.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question with an example. How can I access and change a comment using the ID and using that structure?